# ¿cómo hago para guardar una frase de máximo 100 palabras en un array?

Tags: array

Necesito crear un algoritmo que lea una frase del español de máximo 100 caracteres y determine cuántas palabras, vocales y consonantes tiene.

La condición es que debe realizarse con un array...

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido(a) a SOes. Te invito a leer lo siguiente: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), recuerda que esta comunidad resuelves dudas específicas, no realiza pedidos de códigos o resolución de ejercicios. Por lo tanto, te recomiendo editar tu pregunta, en la cual, agregues el código que tengas hecho y especifiques en detalle, cual es tu duda o el problema que te surge, saludos. ¿Qué haz intentado hacer? ¿Qué lenguaje estás usando?